# mvn clean install, mvn install:install-file order?

Tags: maven

I am learning maven and trying to understand the order of things. As I understand, `mvn clean install` builds the repository with the default jars, where `install` produces a .zip that I will need later.

I want to use my custom jars which I call `mvn install:install-file`, but when I run this before `install`, I get some `cannot find symbol` errors. I am assuming my custom jars (which don't contain these classes) overwrites some default jars? I can't find these classes anywhere on my filesystem, so I am assuming they are already packaged in 1 of the default jars. How can I get around this?

Also, which order should I do things? All I want is the final .zip, that includes the custom jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `mvn install` -- builds and packages the source code and copies ( installs ) the *artifact* to your local repository which is `$USER_HOME/.m2/repository`
2. It's hard to say what's happening there without looking at the command you typed in, and the error trace that you received. That said, `install-file` is to copy an *artifact* to your local repo at appropriate hierarchy. It's nothing more than that. The correct syntax would be:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
       -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   ```
3. Usually, you just need to run `install:install-file` for all the **custom** dependencies once, and before you execute the `mvn install`.
4. If your custom jars have same coordinates -- artifactid, groupid, and version as some of the dependencies in your `pom.xml` and your custom jars do not have the classed that your source code uses -- well, you get the error.

refer: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: I reference a .pom and .jar when I call install-file. I do this for 2 different custom jars. The problem is that when I finally try 'mvn install', it errors on not finding a class (doesn't exist on the file system but it's a dependency in the original .pom). When I clear the repository, a 'mvn clean install' works fine, it's just when I call install-file, does it fail. Does clean go before install-file, am I possibly missing a dependency somewhere in the 'new' pom files I install?

Comment: @user12740 - Check the dependency available for which you are getting error. In my case there is no version available for `Spring Boot 2.5` rather I have to for for `Spring Boot 2.5.0` or `2.5.x` For everything else you can refer to the answer feed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [maven-install-plugin website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) they mention as the following: -

> **install:install-file:** ***is mostly used to install an externally created artifact*** into the local repository, along with its POM. In that case the project information can be taken from an optionally specified pomFile, but can also be given using command line parameters.

This means the artifact should be created before using this command. If you would like to deploy your fresh compiled code to the local repository, please just use the ***mvn clean install***.

Please look at the [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for further information about the sequence and lifecycle. I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.